# Custom Field layouts

Tags: field, layout

So many times im at odds with the layout of Craft Fields in the CMS, where from a usability and user interaction stand point I feel the layout can be way better and even mimic the front end result.

Long and short is, can I edit the layout of fields in the CMS.

The image below is a matrix, but only allows to select how much of an element is take un HORIZONNTALLY

[image]

The ideal here would also to have a vatical selection in the CMS:

[image]

I know thats a hell of alot to ask from the guys at Pixel and Tonic - so instead, im worndering if there is a way for me to acsess this myself, using some custom CMS rules for the CMS.

Pointing me in the right direction would be great :)

Thanks - W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this repository for an example of [Matrix Façades](https://github.com/nystudio107/matrixfacades) which does exactly what you're looking for (article forthcoming)

Comment: Ah the man of the hour! I just watched you on Craft Quest covering this very topic, very cool, but was really confused where to mimic the functionality (have left a comment on the video) - Thanks for link the repository